# DHCP server on T1600G-18TS won't respond to requests

Tags: networking, dhcp, switch, vlan

I recently bought a T1600G-18TS TP-Link smart switch but can't get the DHCP server work on it.

**Packet statistics**

```
T1600G-18TS#show ip dhcp server statistics
Message             Received
BOOTREQUEST         0
DHCPDISCOVER        124
DHCPREQUEST         0
DHCPDECLINE         0
DHCPRELEASE         0
DHCPINFORM          0

Message             Sent
BOOTREPLY           0
DHCPOFFER           0
DHCPACK             0
DHCPNAK             0
```

#### I've tried to

1. Use `/24` netmask instead of `/26`
2. Use different network class
3. Save config and restart
4. Disable and then re-enable dhcp service
5. Factory reset and re-configure

I've also found that the current firmware version is not present on the [TP-Link support page](https://www.tp-link.com/ae/support/download/t1600g-18ts/#Firmware), my switch has version **2.0.5** but on the page the newest version is **2.0.3**.

#### Device info

**Firmware Version:**
2.0.5 Build 20200304 Rel.33762(s)
**Hardware Version:**
T1600G-18TS 2.0

#### Configuration

```
!T1600G-18TS
#
vlan 11
 name "Private"
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
system-time ntp UTC+01:00 133.100.9.2 139.78.100.163 12
no system-time dst
#
#
#
user name admin privilege admin secret 5 <password-hash>
no service reset-disable
#
#
#
#
#
service dhcp server
ip dhcp server pool "Private"
network 192.168.0.64 255.255.255.192
default-gateway 192.168.0.126
dns-server 192.168.0.1
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#

#
#
#
#
#
#
interface vlan 11
  ip address 192.168.0.126 255.255.255.192
  description "Private"
  no ipv6 enable
#
interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/1
  switchport general allowed vlan 11 untagged
  
#
interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/2
  switchport general allowed vlan 11 untagged
  
#
interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/3
  switchport general allowed vlan 11 untagged
  
#
interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/4
  
#
interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/5
  switchport general allowed vlan 11 untagged
  
#
interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/6
  switchport general allowed vlan 11 tagged
  
#
interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/7
  
#
interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/8
  
#
interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/9
  
#
interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/10
  
#
interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/11
  
#
interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/12
  
#
interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/13
  
#
interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/14
  no switchport
  ip address-alloc dhcp
  no ipv6 enable
  
  no ip igmp snooping
  no ipv6 mld snooping
#
interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/15
  
#
interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/16
  
#
interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/17
  
#
interface gigabitEthernet 1/0/18
  
#
end
```

*(The `gigabitEthernet 1/0/14` interface is used for configuration.)*

Comment: Which port are you connecting your device to that you want to get a DHCP IP address for?

Comment: Currently to gigabitEthernet 1/0/2, but tried with other members of VLAN11

Comment: What do you mean by "can't get the DHCP server work **on** it"? What exactly is your problem? Your switch doesn't receive an IP from the DHCP server or a device connected to the switch or both?

Comment: The problem is that the switch won't assign IP addresses to clients. It's a smart switch with DHCP server built in. The 14th ethernet port recives IP from my current DHCP server (which is running on an ubuntu server) so I can configure it from my currently working network.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the manufacturer by email? Something's up with your firmware version, possibly even the wrong firmware loaded on it, or the wrong versions reported on their support site. Hold off on updating that firmware till you know for sure.

Comment: Not yet, but I've been thinking about it. I don't want to touch the firmware since I can't find the original version.

Comment: I just wrote an email through the form on the TP-Link support site. Now waiting for response.

Comment: @NoelNemeth seem to have overlooked the DHCP server option, sorry about that!